# Deriving the Pratt-Arrow Definition

Tags: probability, derivatives

I am looking through the definition of Pratt-Arrow Definition and I saw this equation. I am not sure how this derivation comes about.
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}[U(W+\epsilon)] &\simeq \mathrm{E}\Bigl[U(W)+\epsilon U'(W)+\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}U''(W)\Bigr]\\
&=U(W)+\frac{\sigma_\epsilon^2}{2}U''(W)
\end{align*}$$
([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnlOM.png))

I am not sure how the expectation function changes into the variance part, especially why the $U'(w)$ is missing. Another thing is why is [ϵ]=$$\begin{align*}{\sigma_\epsilon^2}\end{align*}$$?

Need some guidance...

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: It seems to me that the only random variable here is $\epsilon$ and that epsilon follows a distribution with $\mathbb E[\epsilon] = 0$ and $\mathbb V[\epsilon] = \sigma_\epsilon^2$. But this is only guessing, can you provide a source?

Comment: source is: http://www.empiwifo.uni-freiburg.de/lehre-teaching-1/winter-term-10-11/materialien-portfolio-analysis/utility.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, this is a 2nd-order Taylor expansion of the function around $W$. Apparently, $W$ is known (and therefore deterministic) wealth, and $\epsilon$ is some random change in wealth, independent of current level, with $E(\epsilon)=0,\; Var(\epsilon)=E(\epsilon^2)=\sigma_\epsilon^2$.
The general expression for the 2nd-order Taylor expansion of a function $f(x)$ around a point $a$ is

$$f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac12f''(x)(x-a)^2$$

If we set  $x= W+\epsilon$ and $W=a$ , we are evaluating the expected utility from *changed* wealth near its initial magnitude, $W$ before the random shock. Substitute this into the general expression (and also use the  utility function instead of $f$) to obtain
$$U(W+\epsilon) \approx U(W) + U'(W)(W+\epsilon-W) + \frac12U''(W)(W+\epsilon-W)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow U(W+\epsilon) \approx U(W) + U'(W)\epsilon + \frac12U''(W)\epsilon^2$$

Take the expected value, remember that $W$ is deterministic and independent of $\epsilon$, as well as the specification of $\epsilon$, and you're done.